# Deeply Nested Data - Properties in AgensGraph

Tags: database, graph, cypher, agens-graph

Can we have highly nested properties in AgensGraph for our vertexes or edges?

Answer (score 2):

Unless other graph databases such as Neo4j, in AgensGraph properties, can have nested JSON objects as their values. AgensGraph uses PostgreSQL’s JSONB and any data type supported by PostgreSQL can be stored into the properties of vertices and edges.

So the answer is yes, you can have highly nested properties in AgensGraph for your vertexes or edges.

**Example:**

```
CREATE (:person{name:'Tom',phone:{home:'4086513728',work:{num:'4089665432',direct:'444'},mobile:'4084563112'}})-[:knows{fromdate:'2011-11-24'}]->(:person{name:'Bob'});
```